# How to make a splash screen image stay on screen for 5 seconds in Pygame?

Tags: python, time, pygame, delay, wait

I have a simple Pygame game which I need to create a splash screen for that displays the game name for 5 seconds. This is currently being achieved by blitting some standard text to the display surface and calling pygame.time.delay(5000).
However, whilst the 5 seconds elapse my game does not seem to be capturing any events. The event procedure is located in a while True: loop below the splash screen function but it is obvious that pygame.time.delay() is freezing my entire code... but I need the event procedure to still function so I can detect quit /escape key (to skip the splash screen) events.

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Pygame you can use the [pygame.time.get_ticks](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) function when the splash screen appears and record this time. Continue getting input from the user and calling `get_ticks` to see if 5000 milliseconds have elapsed and when it has you may discontinue the splash screen and continue as normal.

Comment: Rather `start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks(); while pygame.time.get_ticks() < start_time+5000:`

Comment: yeah just figured that